# creating an array of abjects from a list in R with toJSON

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I am creating an JSON file from a list in R. The format of the list is quite nested.

"ageValues", whereby "ageValues" is repeated many time, always with a differnt name. The list in R looks like:

```
   ageBucket <-  list(startAge = 0L, endAge = 59L, price = 0, expectedInsureds = 0)

ageValue <- as.array(list(price = 0, expectedInsureds = 0))
noAgeValues <- 59
ageValues <- rep(list(ageValue), noAgeValues+1)
names(ageValues) <- c(1:60)
ageBucket <- c(ageBucket, (ageValue = list(ageValues)))
toJSON(ageBucket)
```

I want to create an JSOn file of this format:

```
...[{ "price": 0, "expectedInsureds": 0 }, ... ]...
```

but i am getting this instead:

```
...{"price":[0],"expectedInsureds":[0]},...
```

How can this be done, without changing the argument in `toJSON(ageBucket)`

i tried:

```
lapply(ageValues, function(x) as.array(x, letters))
```

but i guess i am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Could you provide the definition of ageBucket?

Comment: Feel free to also look at this for how to best provide your example for others to look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the **auto_unbox = T** option:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(ageBucket,auto_unbox = T,pretty = TRUE)
```

The other universal solution is to remove the square brackets in json object, e.g.

```
jsonlite::toJSON(ageBucket) %>% 
gsub(pattern = "\\[|\\]", replacement = "")
```

Comment: as i mentioned in my question, i cannot change the arguments in toJSON, since it would adversely affect other parts of my file

Comment: Have you trid the  "gsub" solution?. It is not related with the arguments in toJSON

Comment: as i said, ageBucket is just a section of my larger file. gsub would change the whole file, analogously to changing toJSON arguments, right?

Comment: Alright. I still don't understand.  Honestly speaking,  the code I provide can satisfy "I want to create an JSOn file of this format".   You  say you have trid to use a function on ageValues, i.e., "lapply(ageValues, function(x) as.array(x, letters))" .  In my opinion, any operation on ageValues will not solve the problem. 
Use gsub is an universal solution even for your larger file, it will not spend too much time. Don't struggle that  it would change the whole file. Just a suggestion. 
Otherwise, I  don't know what's the level of solution you want.

Comment: Even for a simplest list,  a <- list(startAge = 0L, endAge = 59L),
toJSON(a)  will still appear the square barckets [].